# Ionic 3 - Modal screen with rounded corners

Tags: css, ionic-framework, modal-dialog, ionic3, modalviewcontroller

How to round a modal screen like this [link](https://i.pinimg.com/236x/a9/7b/5c/a97b5c103c945d0cb0aba5fed9cb9f11.jpg) ?

My CSS code is:

```
.modal {
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
   padding: 25% 15%  !important;
   display: block;
   border-radius: 25px;
 }
```

modal.html

```
   <ion-content>
     <div class="subtitulo">
       <h4>Select your city</h4>
     </div>

    <ion-list>
      <button ion-item *ngFor="let cidade of cidades" (click)="selCidade(cidade)" detail-none>
        <h3 text-wrap>{{ cidade.nome }}</h3>
        <ion-icon name="ios-arrow-forward" item-right></ion-icon>
      </button>
     </ion-list>
   </ion-content>
```

But the border-radius have no effect. I tried some tutorials, but no one has effect.

I need some help in CSS for this case

Tks,

Comment: Your above code should work fine. Please update your question so that it shows **all** your relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: update code... modal html

Comment: check it https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/custom-modal-alert-with-html-form/47980/29

Comment: modal.html updated. The css is passed when i call the modal page:

Comment: Utpaul, i already tried the code on this page.

Answer (score 5):

Just posting the solution for ionic 4:

in global.scss, just change the scss variable of the ionic component "ion-modal"

```
ion-modal {
  --border-radius: 8px!important;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

1. create a css into your css / scss file:

```
   .square-modal .modal-wrapper { border-radius: 0px; }
```

2. use the css into your model creation:

```
  async presentModal() {

    const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
      component: InvestorListPage,
      componentProps: { id: 5, name: 'gaurav' },
      cssClass: 'square-modal'
    });

    modal.onDidDismiss().then(result => {
      console.log(result.data);
    });

    return await modal.present();

  }
```

(tested with ionic4)

Comment: This helped. Only thing is the SCSS styling should be written in `global.scss` file. You can edit you post. :) I tried in Ionic 4 referring this [post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-modal-size/152372?u=chilupa).

Answer (score 2):

if your page is named "modal", you can try adding `border-radius: 25px;` to the `page-modal` in the modal.scss file:

```
page-modal{
   border-radius: 25px;
}
```

it works perfect for me:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAhN5.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `overflow: hidden`. I hope it's will work.

Thanks